# SQL Server 2016 Query Crashes Server

Tags: sql-server, memory

SQL Server 2016 continually crashes when running an ETL source query. Memory starts consuming at a fantastic rate then hits max and the service shuts off. This seems ridiculous, especially since the query runs perfectly on SQL Server 2014 with less memory and slower disks. <<s>What could have changed and more importantly, is there a way to change server query or memory settings in 2016 that will prevent this crash scenario?</s> **Can anyone narrow the issue (and confirm it's a bug) or provide a more robust work around?**

MAXDOP is set to 4, min memory is 8000 max is 24000 with 28gb on the system. The SQL 2014 machine had SharePoint running on it also (different SQL instance), and as a result has a lower max memory (12533mb). The SQL 2016 machine is an exact copy except it does not have the SharePoint install and was upgraded to SSDs.

The query only has 9 columns (6 INTs) for 7,122,737 records with two small table joins and minimal filtering... there's nothing that can change with the query and again it was working perfectly on SQL 2014. In fact, it runs a minute faster in SQL 2014 vs SQL 2016 despite the SSDs and almost twice the memory additions to a supposedly faster release!

[image]

So after a lot of searching, multiple different installs reverting to a database only install in default locations I have mostly identified the issue. One of the columns being hashed is a `VARCHAR(MAX)` which triggers a massive memory request from `HASHBYTES`. Not entirely unreasonable, even though the longest column is actually only 49 characters. Source system... work around will be to cast it dynamically I think.

If SQL Server reaches max memory, which it quickly arrives at with this query it crashes. This seems hit and miss, and may generate other errors instead, leaving the server up. Adding DISTINCT ensures the crash behavior unless excessive amounts of memory are present.

I've created a Microsoft Connect issue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E17sw.png) if you have additional testing or ideas or can reproduce the issue. I'd say this is only partially the answer as it is still merely narrowed to a range of possibilities, that I don't have the time or capability to fully identify. However, it does not appear to be general memory pressure or a result of general SQL 2016 setup and services.

**The following can reproduce the issue.**

```
CREATE TABLE Testing (
    VarCharMAX VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    VarCharRealistic VARCHAR(100) NULL
) ON PRIMARY
GO

SELECT TOP 1000000
    IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS Number
INTO Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns x
CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns
GO --Ensure 1 million rows were inserted

INSERT INTO Testing
        (VarCharMAX, VarCharRealistic)
SELECT
     CAST(Number As VARCHAR(MAX)) + 'a' AS VarCharMAX
    ,CAST(Number As VARCHAR(100)) + 'a' AS VarCharRealistic
FROM Numbers
GO

--Server crash under ~16GB memory
SELECT DISTINCT
    HASHBYTES('md5', VarCharMAX)
FROM dbo.Testing
```

Comment: What the heck.  Any differences in the execution plans per chance?  I haven't seen this before personally

Comment: You'll likely get more meaningful answers if you include a repro.

Comment: Can you paste the full error messages too? We can only see the beginning in the screenshot.

Comment: @MaxVernon and everyone else - It looks like a lower level server issue as I've looked at it more. I've added more from the log and execution plans though. Maybe we can at least narrow it enough I can post the now relevant additional info. Thanks!

Comment: `SQL 2014 machine had SharePoint` .. does not sharepoint require `maxdop 1` ? You can run `sqldiag.exe` to capture and find what exactly is going on when the crash happens. When SQL Server crashes, did it generate stack dumps ? What is logged in windows event log when sql server crashes ?

Comment: @Kin Sorry, SharePoint had a different instance on 2014 machine... mentioned because it was consuming resources. Updated with event log, SQLDIAG was running but couldn't complete after the service crash.

Comment: If you are able to isolate the problem to one particularly query, you could try a `MAX` memory hint, capping it before it shuts the server down.  At least then you would be able to do a little more troubleshooting.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/06/09/new-memory-grant-query-hint-min_grant_percent-came-to-rescue/

Comment: @Dave I ran the repro and able to crash SQL. **But with query hint `SELECT DISTINCT
    HASHBYTES('md5', VarCharMAX)
FROM dbo.Testing option (maxdop 1)`, I am able to select all distinct 1M rows in 17 sec**.

Comment: @Kin interesting, thanks! I'll test and likely use in my ETL to use that as it seems the most reliable and simplest change.

Comment: @Dave test it out though. When I lowered my test machine's max memory to 6GB, SQL Server crashes. So, I think this has to do with SQL Server starving on memory grant & parallelism for the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I might have a legit answer .. and its a bug.

*[(similar was found when running checkdb in 2014 & fixed in SP1 + CU1)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3034615)*

When I run the query as is, SQL Server crashes

> 2016-06-16 17:27:32.00 spid37s      Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 1

And in the error log I see :

```
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 0)                KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                       0
VM Committed                                      0
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
SM Reserved                                       0
SM Committed                                      0
Pages Allocated                            10678248  ==> 10GB !!
2016-06-16 17:27:32.00 spid37s
```

With `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` => serial execution

```
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 0)        KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              0
VM Committed                             0
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
SM Reserved                              0
SM Committed                             0
Pages Allocated                          144
```

Please test it in your environment and let me know.

Comment: The query hint allows it to complete. I think the `VARCHAR(MAX)` plays into this issue too though: adding `CAST(VARCHAR(100))` reduces memory use and query execution time by a lot! ... but perhaps that would happen regardless of any other issues.

Comment: @Dave good point. With `VarCharRealistic` the query runs without the hint capping the max memory to mere 6GB as well. So you have to decide whether to use `VarCharRealistic` & not use query hint or use query hint and go with `varcharMax` :-)